# fork() signal Child and Parent Process in C

Tags: c, signals, fork

I am confused on how signals work in this code snipet and having trouble what exactly is the child and parent process. 
I know the result for the child process is

```
StayHome
```

and the parent process ouput is:

```
Paris
```

I am confused about what exactly does

```
signal(SIGUSR1, Paris);
```

and

```
kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
```

I initially thought that the code would run and print out due to the fork as

```
London
StayHome
Paris
```

I guess I still need clarification what a child and parent process is.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile int city = 0;
static void display(void)
{
    if (city == 1) printf("Paris\n");
    else if (city == 2) printf("London\n");
    else printf("StayHome\n");
}

static void Paris(int sig)
{
    city = 1;
}

static void London(int sig)
{
    city = 2;
}


int main(void)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    signal(SIGUSR1, Paris);
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d\n",pid);

    switch(pid){
    case -1:
        exit(0);
    case 0:
       display();
       kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
       display();
       break;
    default:
       city = 2;
       wait(&status);
       display();
       break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You better do more research both on `fork` and what happens when it succeeds, as well as how signals work. There are thousands of tutorials for both all over the Internet.

Comment: How is `city` defined?

Comment: The child process (`pid == 0`) prints twice — once before `city` is set to non-zero, once after it is set by function `Paris()`.  (Note that function `London()` is never used — it should be omitted.)  The parent process (`pid != 0`) waits for the child to finish before printing its city — which was assigned to `2` aka `London`.  So, the expected output should be 2 PID numbers — one of which will be zero, and all three names in a specific sequence (which you should be seeing — it isn't clear whether you are seeing it).  After a `fork()`, the child gets the value `0` returned from `fork()`.

Comment: Note that after the `fork()`, the two processes are independent and do not share any variables — and specifically, `city` is set independently in each process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm slightly confused why you ever thought that it would print London?

Regardless here is code that runs and would print

```
StayHome
StayHome
London
```

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

volatile int    city = 0;

static void display(void)
{
    if (city == 1)
        printf("Paris\n");
    else if (city == 2)
        printf("London\n");
    else
        printf("StayHome\n");
}

static void Paris(int sig)
{
    city = 1;
    (void)sig;
}

static void London(int sig)
{
    city = 2;
    (void)sig;
}

int main(void)
{
    int     status;
    pid_t   pid;
    pid_t   parent;

    parent = getpid();
    signal(SIGUSR1, London);
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (!pid)
    {
        display();
        kill(parent, SIGUSR1);
        display();
    }
    else
    {
        city = 2;
        wait(&status);
        display();
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Keep in mind if you want to change the state of the parent process then you need the PID of the parent process (so store it before you fork). Then when you're signaling it you're changing the city of the parent ID to 2 (`London`);however, the child process still never changes its state to anything other than 0 so you're staying with the printed result `StayHome`. Hopefully this helped :D

Comment: I got confused about it printing london because originally this was a problem given from my professor, and i thought printing the PID would give me an id of how the fork would operate through the swtich. It first printed a number 7980, and the other was 0. i knew that 7980 was the parent and 0 is usually the child, therefore i thought it would print the parent, which would equal to _london_, and then go to the 'case 0:' which i thought would print _stayhome_ and _paris_. This was without taking consideration of signal which is more clear!

Comment: @RaySousa Glad I could help :)

Comment: @RaySousa If you could mark the answer as correct it'd be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in multiprocess/multithread programming you cannot say which program comes to execute first. If the child output is `StayHome` and the parent's is `London` I think you might get both

```
StayHome
London
```

or

```
London
StayHome
```

In this case `wait` should block the parent until the child is executed.

Back to your program. `city = 0` at first. `signal(SIGUSR1, Paris);` registers the function `Paris` when `SIGUSR` event happens. This will be valid both for the parent and the child since one is the copy of the other.

`pid = fork();` creates a new process and assigns to `pid` `0` if we are inside the child process, the child process id if the parent is executing.

The child process executes the branch switch with `0`: it first call `display` and being `city = 0` it will print `StayHome`. Then it kills itself sending the signal `SIGUSR1`. This will call the function `Paris` which sets city to 1.
I did not think the second `display()` would be called because the child process has killed itself but it does so this will print `Paris`.

Now the child process is terminated and the parent program exits from `wait`, sets `city=2` and the call to display will print `London`